# Reading from serial port [loop]

Tags: python, serial

I would like to read from the USB serial port from time to time in a loop.
I can open the port and read data with:

import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while 1 :
    ser.readline()

An Arduino Uno is connected to the USB port of the RPi.
The Arduino acts as a sensor and it will constantly produce readings.

I need some help in adding timing features to the above code.
I want to open the port and read from it for a certain period of time. After that period of time, the port closes and the received data will be analysed.
After a pause of several minutes, the port will reopen and the RPi will read data from it again.
This continues in a loop.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

All you would need to add, aside from closing the port when you're done ;), is `import time` and then use [`time.sleep(secs)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep):

```
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

while 1:
    serial_line = ser.readline()

    print(serial_line) # If using Python 2.x use: print serial_line
    # Do some other work on the data

    time.sleep(300) # sleep 5 minutes

    # Loop restarts once the sleep is finished

ser.close() # Only executes once the loop exits
```

I don't know if pySerial is buffered (data sent while sleeping is stored or simply dropped), but I usually prefer to use a generator, if you don't explicitly need to wait. They seem a bit more flexible (in my opinion):

```
def serial_data(port, baudrate)
    ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate)

    while True:
        yield ser.readline()

    ser.close()

for line in serial_data('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600):
    [...transform data...]
```

You might also be able to use the `with` syntax instead of the while, but I'm not too sure how that'd work with pySerial.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. In your first example with pySerial, I would like for the serial port to reopen after a period of time. To do so, do I add another time.sleep() after ser.close in another loop?

Comment: It doesn't seem that pySerial closes the serial port after `readline`, so unless you're doing more work that uses the serial port, you can just move the `ser.close()` down.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by moving the ser.close() down?

Comment: I was just editing my comment to clarify, but locked after 5 minutes :/

The `ser.close()` never runs until the while loop is done (which doesn't really ever occur since it's `while 1`/`while true`), so the serial port isn't actually closed between `readline()` calls. Since simply having a pySerial port open isn't blocking, that shouldn't be an issue. If the while loop only ran x number of times, and then you wanted to work on that the port again, just leave the port open until done (move `ser.close()` after all code that interacts with the port).

Comment: Note however that some methods are blocking during execution, [`readline`](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.FileLike) being one of them if no timeout is provided during the serial object instantiation.

In the first example, you're wanting to analyze some data between `readline()` calls, so let me see if my edit can clarify what you might do a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the Serial Library and install in Python Lib Folder. Then use the following script. Please modify loop to your requirements. The `sys.argv[]` are used for seeking Params at command line. You may omit this and hardcode as per your requirement.

```
import sys 
import serial
import time
param1 = sys.argv[1]
param2 = sys.argv[2]
#param2=sys.argv[3]
ard = serial.Serial(param1, param2, timeout=0)
RFIDNum = ard.readline() # read all characters in buffer
#time.sleep(1) 
print RFIDNum
```